# Hibernate, Postgre/MySQL discrepancy

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, postgresql, spring-boot

When I run my application against a MySQL database, everything goes as expected.
When I try the same against a Postgre database it errors out...

The following is the output from the logs.

https://gist.github.com/stelar7/f8414971e8ee130c977346c4baae9d7b

Comment: It's possible that  bigserial (auto-increment) , which is actually a bigint in PostgreSQL (8 bytes wide unsigned) doesn't fit in a Java Long type ( also 8 bytes but signed). Try changing to serial in your database or use BigInteger in your Hibernate entity.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` on you `application.properties` solves the problem?

Comment: Nope, it changes nothing.